Flask and logging - some questions
I. When creating a Flask application, where exactly do I initialize logging?
Right before app = Flask(__name__) ?
Right after it?
II. By default, Flask logs HTTP requests in the common format, i.e.
- 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2024 20:39:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

How can I change it to the following?
Received POST request "/rest/api/1234/567" from IP 192.168.0.1. Content-Type =
"application/json", Content-Length = 12345, User-Agent = "Mozilla 1.2.3"

III. Last but not least, does the development server included with Flask have some shutdown handler that can be registered to? When user presses Ctrl+C to kill it, I would like to perform some final cleanup operations...

In-app logging customization
For customizing logging for Flask, you can refer to the docs here
You can override or disable the default app logger with your custom logger with added functionalities.
Shutdown Handlers
Coming to the shutdown handlers, there are no built-in handlers in the Flask.
For a platform-independent solution, Flask provides a more compatible method for registering shutdown behavior via the teardown_appcontext or atexit handlers.
from flask import Flask
import atexit

app = Flask(__name__)

def shutdown_handler():
    # Perform cleanup tasks here
    print("Shutting down...")

atexit.register(shutdown_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

